# Return Python Django model as a json object

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return an object created from a Django model as JSON to the rest framework after being created. I have tried many ways but they all don't seem to work. Here is my code;

```
router.register(r'amazon/products/import/(?P<id>[-\w\d]+)', amazon_views.AmazonImportProductViewSet, base_name='import-amazon-product')
```

...routing to...

```
class AmazonImportProductViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, id=None):
        product = simple_amazon.lookup(ItemId=id, ResponseGroup='ItemAttributes,Offers,Images,EditorialReview,Reviews')
        brand = get_object_or_404(AmazonBrand, name="microsoft")
        createdProduct = AmazonProduct.objects.create(title=product.title, brand=brand)
        #json_p = serializers.serialize("json", createdProduct)
        serializer = AmazonProductSerializer(createdProduct)
        return Response({'success': "true", 'message':'Imported successfully!', 'product':serializer.data})
```

I am trying to return just 1 object with it's OneToMany relationships. For example I would like brand returned as well.

Comment: Check this http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: My code is very similar to one of the samples in that doc but returning it to the browser I get the error `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.`

Comment: If I add ` context={'request': request}` I get; Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "api:amazonproduct-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field. I think this is assuming something else while I am just try to return the object as JSON.

Comment: Do you have `product` viewset? Did you register it by router?

Comment: I don't want to have the viewset set to be able to return the createdProduct as JSON. I think my entire method is wrong including using `router.register`. So I am looking for an alternative if it is wrong.

Comment: Just try nested relation instead of HyperlinkedField. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: Okay, I see what you meant. I just had to change my serializer from `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` to `serializers.ModelSerializer`

Comment: ...and add `brand = AmazonBrandSerializer(many=False, read_only=True )` to my serializer. Yes that worked!

Comment: Just a hint for the next time, for a question like that it would be easier to also add the serializer to your code. And for further development I would recommend reading the DRF tutorial again http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/. Also considering your comments I would recommend to checkout the generic views: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/ they might easy our tasks a little